# how to custom the position of Tab widget when I put a TaBar widget in SafeArea widget

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I've changed the question from center the `Tab` to customize the position of the `Tab`.
Because I noticed that the `Tab` is actually Centered and according to the [document](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html), it just adding paddings.
But if you want a TabBar whenever it avoid safe area or not the elements in tabs are aligned centered (automatically), I can't find a way now.

[image: screenshot]
look at the screenshot above, the icons/titles successfully avoid the black bar area (by extend the height of Tabbar), but not vertically center aligned. I tried put a `Center` element to wrap the tabar to tab widget, It extend the height to the whole screen.

I also tried wrap the tab in a `Container` widget and get the `height` property set, but it seems all the height are avoid the safe area (by add the a const).
And I tried wrap the whole `Scaffold` with a `SafeArea` widget, but the safe area become black and we actually wish the tab bat become higher and then layout element in this higher container, but not just move the container.

So the question might be How can I custom the position of the `Tab` widget. because the Tabbar is actually centered, but it layout child elements by avoid the safe area, so it's not visually vertical-aligned.

my code is:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final icons = [Icons.library_books, Icons.photo, Icons.toc];
  return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: Material(
        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        child: SafeArea(child: TabBar(
          controller: _tabController,
          tabs: _titles.map((t) {
            final i = _titles.indexOf(t);
            return Tab(
              text: t,
              icon: Icon(icons[i]),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: <Widget>[
          PostListPage(
            userid: widget.userid,
            username: widget.username,
          ),
          AlbumListPage(
            userid: widget.userid,
            username: widget.username,
          ),
          TodoListPage(
            userid: widget.userid,
            username: widget.username,
          ),
        ],
      )
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: A little more code would help. But, have you tried to use the SafeArea widget as the parent of the Scaffold, instead of inside the BottomTabBar?

Comment: @chemamolins that's the whole build method, a simple demo page, 3 tab with 3 tabview. I tried use SafeArea widget wrap the Scaffold, and the safe area become black(no widgets in it), and if I put SafeArea in bottomNavBar, at least the whole visible area is blue.

Comment: Yeah, but if I want to reproduce your problem I don't have the rest of the code. A minimal example that shows what you mean would be great. Also it is difficult to understand the problem from the image. What exactly is the problem? That the list tile are not vertically centered?

Comment: @chemamolins the question is the tab widget are not vertical-center aligned as the image show. not the listview thing. if the icon and title can move down by 10pt more or less, it's centered in visual. And I found it's actually centered aligned, just added external padding at the bottom, and I want to adjust the position

Comment: @chemamolins I alos post a [reply](https://twitter.com/walkerwzy/status/1029193235170652163) on twitter at flutter's account

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I understand what you want now and I'm afraid it's not achievable.

If you don't use the SafeArea widget, the bar has the normal height at the full bottom and everything is centered. It has the disadvantage that it is over the black area in iPhone X.

But if you want to avoid the black bar area, you have to use the SafeArea (as you do) which adds some padding and pushes everything up a little, thus avoiding the bottom "unsafe" area.

So, it is the padding added by SafeArea which prevents you from pushing down (centering) the titles and icons.

A possible option is to wrap the SafeArea with a Container with a black color so the unsafe area is black.

```
child: Container(
  color: Colors.black,
  child: SafeArea(child: TabBar(
          controller: _tabController,
...
```

Comment: so , even if I can customize the tab item's position, I still should also know  it has been added additional padding or not (in different devices), it will become more and more complex.I now just leave it alone with large empty space now.